# Which Barcode Scanner to be used with arduino in India

Tags: arduino-uno

I know this question is not so releavant as it does not include any research, but I am in search of a barcode scanner that i can easily interface with arduino and get output from it but unfortunately the Scanner models which are listed from the people doing the same stuff are not easily available in India. So if anyone knows which barcode scanner would best suit the requirement please suggest.
Availabilty in **Indian** market would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most barcode scanners behave just like a regular keyboard.

Try getting one with a PS2 port. You can pretty easily interface a PS2 keyboard to an Arduino. There are already libraries for it.